# Seeing Events in Properties window for controls in EditItemTemplate

Tags: asp.net, webforms, templatefield

My application is using ASP.NET Webforms.  I am trying to see the events for a control (a button control in this case) that I have in an EditItemTemplate.  The events don't show in the Properties window when I select the control in the Source view; you apparently have to be in Design view for control events to show up in the Properties window.  But since the control is in an EditItemTemplate, I can't seem to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

To view the events for a control click the **lightning bolt** in the properties window after selecting the control in either source view (click the control's markup) or design view.

To enable the events drop-down in code-behind for page events select **Tools\Options** then **All Languages** and check/re-check **Navigation Bar**.